# EmberJS - Strange Behavior Retrieving Model from Controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I also posted this on discuss.emberjs.com but trying to see if anyone here knows the solution. So I am trying to retrieve the model from the ArrayController but for some reason I cannot retrieve it as it is giving me undefined/empty arrays.

On my init function in the ArrayController, I have the following:

```
init: function(){
    this._super();
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.content);
    console.log(this.get('content'));
    console.log(this.model);
    console.log(this.get('model'));
}
```

"this.content" and "this.model" evaluates as undefined. Both .get() returns an empty array. But the strange thing is that "console.log(this);" prints the following:

```
Class {_subControllers: Array[0], toString: function, __ember1409674198526: "ember453", 
    __ember_meta__: Object, constructor: function…}
    __ember1409674198526: "ember453"
    __ember_meta__: Object
    __nextSuper: undefined
    _qpDelegate: function (controller, prop) {
    _subControllers: Array[0]
    model: Class
        __ember1409674198526: "ember392"
        __ember_meta__: Object
        __nextSuper: undefined
        content: Array[8]
        isLoaded: true
        isUpdating: false
        store: Class
        toString: function () { return ret; }
        type: my-app-v3@model:suit:
        __proto__: Object
    toString: function () { return ret; }
    __proto__: Object
```

So "this" has model I need under model->content (the array of 8 elements). I'm really confused to why I am getting these errors when just accessing the inner elements of "this".

Anyone know why this strange behavior is happening?

For reference, I am using Ember-CLI (0.0.42).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your immediate problem, try this:

```
    App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
        init: function () {
            this._super();
            var that = this;
            Ember.run.next(function () {
                console.log(that);
                console.log(that.get('model'));
            });
        }
    });
```

As for the technical explanation of this anomaly, note that `console.log()` doesn't really stringifies the object in its state at the time of the call. Instead, it remembers the reference to the object, allowing you to "explore" it dynamically. The object, however, remains the same and any changes on it are reflected in the console.

So, at the time init() is called, the `this` reference really doesn't have `model` property. That's why `console.log(this.model)` produces nothing. However, immediately after init, the model is populated. So by the time you inspect your console, you can see it in the cached `this` reference.

To confirm this, put a break point just after console.log calls and inspect the console output while paused. Model properties won't be there.

Answer (score 2):

It might be that you're logging from the controller's `init` method, which I don't believe is a recommended pattern.

Typically, you'd manipulate a controller in the `setupController` hook of a `Route`. At that point, a controller's model is guaranteed to have been resolved and you should have no problems accessing it via `controller.get('content')`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So maybe I should explain the context a bit -- I want to run a function whenever the controller is initialized that creates an array from the model's data which then the template displays. Which is why I wanted to retrieve the current model from the controller and traverse through its data. Am I pretty much forced to use Ember Views for this?

Comment: @user1781768 [setupController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController), takes two paramters `controller` and `model`. you can traverse/modify the model there and call `this._super(controller, modifiedModel)`.

Comment: Another way to go about this would be to create a computed property on your controller, which would update whenever the controller's content changes, and would return a *new* array of objects that you can use in your template with {{#each}}{{/each}}.